# How to fix imperfect shapes using opencv

Tags: opencv

I have a list of images like [this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21642925/shoe.tif) (sorry I don't have sufficient reputation to embed the image in my question) and I'd like to fix their imperfections using opencv. By 'fixing' I mean that the white areas biting parts in the shoe shape should be filled with black. It should look like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21642925/shoe2.tif). This correction was obtained manually.

I don't have an analytic definition for the shapes or for the imperfections I'm dealing with, but the example mentioned above and the imperfections it shows are pretty representative. These shapes have outlines with smooth-gradual changes. I assume that the key for identifying imperfections is to spot places where the change in the outline is abrupt. However, I don't know how to translate this intuition into an algorithm (which can rely on existing algorithms in opencv of course).

Can someone suggest a way to fix such imperfections using opencv? It doesn't have to reach a perfect result, but at least to reasonably improve the original state. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way to remove these kind of imperfections is to erode the image and then dilate it to recover the area. The erosion will fill the imperfections of the image, but the area of the shoe will increase. Then, you can apply a dilation to restore the area.

You can find [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) an example of using both morphological operators (erosion and dilation). [Erode](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode) and [dilate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate) documenation can help you too.

Comment: Thanks! a sequential call to erode() and dilate() with an elliptic structuring element worked great.